# How to merge data in id already exisits using EF

Tags: c#, .net, list, entity-framework

I Have code like this.

DTO class as follows,

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserInternalId { get; set; }
    public string UserNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

This is how insertion happening

```
public Member(IClientContextFactory contextFactory, IMapper mapper, int tenantId)
{
    this.context = contextFactory.GetContext(tenantId);
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

public void InsertMembers(List<UserDTO> users)
{
    List<EFModel.ClientData.Member> membersInEfModel = new List<EFModel.ClientData.Member>();
    mapper.Map<List<MemberDto>, List<EFModel.ClientData.Member>>(users, membersInEfModel);

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        context.users.AddRange(membersInEfModel);
        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

My problem is When `InsertMembers()` calling with new `userList` previously inserted user details deleting and only new list save in the DB. instead of that, here unique identifier is `UserId`. If already that `userId` is in the DB I need to update particular record and if not exists I need to insert. how can I do this.

Comment: @AFarmanbar can please give me a code answer sir, please

Comment: Some points: Consider using Find instead of FirstOrDefault if the userid is the PK. Consider using Async wherever possible (FindAsync, SaveChangesAsync). I'm not sure I'd turn off change detection for this but if I did I'd do it with a try finally pattern to make sure it was turned back on

Comment: If the PK field has a value, EF will update instead of insert. You don't need the TransactionScope, since `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. The `TransactionScope` only causes problems here, by keeping transactions and connections open longer than necessary

Comment: `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` why?? You *are* making and saving changes. If the context is short lived, as it should, there shouldn't be any reason to disable changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use is

```
public void InsertMembers(List<UserDTO> users)
    {
        List<EFModel.ClientData.Member> membersInEfModel = new List<EFModel.ClientData.Member>();
        mapper.Map<List<MemberDto>, List<EFModel.ClientData.Member>>(users, membersInEfModel);

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            
            foreach (var member in membersInEfModel)
            {
                var existedMember = context.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == member.UserId);
                if (existedMember == null)
                {
                    context.users.Add(member);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, its executing now without any errors. but when there is no matching records found, that records not inserting to the db. any idea sir?

Comment: I'm getting this error. `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded`

Comment: to avoid this I changed this `context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;` into `context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Added`; But now new records inserting without updating already existing once